# How to save some variables ( not all )

Tags: programming

suppose i have a function

```
a[x_]:=a[x-1]+a[x-2] ;a[1]=a[0]=0
```

and i want to save the value  a[2] (not all a[2],a[1],a[0] like using Dumpsave because by doing that my pc will run out of ram at some point.)  How could i do that ?

(* the reason why Shift+Enter is not a choice is  there are many a[ ]s and the function is not as simple as this so it will be much faster if i could store all value of a[ ]s in last calculation. )  ((Sorry for very bad English)

---

this is my problem 
i have these inputs

```
a[n_, m_, i_] := 
 a[n, m, i] = (1/4) (a[n + 1, m, i - 1] + a[n - 1, m, i - 1] + 
     a[n, m + 1, i - 1] + a[n, m - 1, i - 1])

a[n_, m_, 0] := a[n, m, 0] = Mod[n, 100] Mod[m, 100]
```

the first code tells you that the value of a[m,n,i] comes from all its neighboring points but at difference time (i)

the second code tells you about the initial condition of each a[m,n,0]

if i want to fine a[1,1,10000] i cant run it in one time because my pc will run out of memory.  So the way i do is by 
1.finding all values of a[m,n,100]s and store all these values in a variable(which i name it to be a100) 
2.starting new nb. and writing  those two code(above) down 
3.importing all values from a100 to each a[m,n,100]
4.replacing 0 in the second code with 100 ( to make new initial condition)
5.run the first code but this time the value of i will be 200

I tried to write down all these actions(1-5 above) in a new nb. and then just run each line from the start till  the end but doing this takes too much time and i have to do it manually. So i wonder is there i way to run each line automatically from the start or is there a way to collect the all the values of all a[m,n,100]s faster than these  or *is there a way to find a[1,1,10000] fast*

Answer (score 3):

With the given initial conditions (`a[1] = a[0] = 0`), `a[x]` is zero for all `x`

```
RSolve[{a[x] == a[x - 1] + a[x - 2], a[1] == a[0] == 0}, a[x], x][[1]]

(*  {a[x] -> 0}  *)
```

Changing the initial conditions to `a[1] = 1; a[0] = 0;`

```
RSolve[{a[x] == a[x - 1] + a[x - 2], a[1] == 1, a[0] == 0}, a[x], x][[1]]

(*  {a[x] -> Fibonacci[x]}  *)

% // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify

(*  {a[x] -> ((1 + Sqrt[5])^x - 
          (-1 + Sqrt[5])^x*Cos[Pi*x])/
       (2^x*Sqrt[5])}  *)
```

`Fibonacci[x]` encapsulates the value of `a[x]` for all real `x`; consequently, you need only save the expression `Fibonacci[x]` to save `a[x]` for all real `x`

```
Plot[Fibonacci[x], {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: sorry for not stating my problem clearly... actually, there are three arguments in a[] which is a[m,n,i] and  the value of a[m,n,i+1]  is the mean  value of all neighboring points around a[m,n,i] ( such as a[m,n+1,i] ,a[m+1,n,i ) .  The problem is i want to store all a[m,n,i]   (not a[m,n,i-1] for any (m,n) )   because  i only need a[m,n,i] to compute  a[m,n,i+1]

Comment: @SurayuthPintawong Please update your question with a minimal self-contained example.